# Set selector value from JSON receive

Tags: jquery, json

I have a html side where I receive a JSON object from a back-end function in the following format

```
{“p”: “off”, “h”: “off”, “t”: “32”}
```

I would like to compare the values I receive and update the select and slider option values (for example set the selector to on if I receive "on" in the JSON parameter)

For that I am using jQuery but I cant get the #power selector to change value no matter what I try

Probably really simple if you know how to do ...

Can someone please help me?

HTML & Script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="header">
<h1>TEST</h1>
</div>
<form>
<div class = "ui-field-contain">
<select id = "power">
<option option value = "0">Power OFF</option>
<option option value = "1">Power ON</option>
</select>
<select id = "heater">
<option value value = "0">Heater OFF</option>
<option value value = "1">Heater ON</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
<label for="slider">Temp: </label>
<input type="range" name="temp" id="temp" value="38" min="20" max="42" data-highlight = "true">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Set Temp">
</select>
<script>

setInterval(function() {
  updateStatus();
}, 2000); //2000mSeconds update rate

function updateStatus(){
  $.getJSON('/status.json', function(data){
    if ($('#power').html(data.p) == "off") {
        $("#power").val($("#power option:eq(0)").val());
        $("#power").selectmenu("refresh");
        }
  }).fail(function(err){
    console.log("err getJSON mesures.json "+JSON.stringify(err));
  });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON strings have to be enclosed in straight double quotes, not curly quotes.

Comment: What is `if ($('#power').html(data.p) == "off") {` supposed to do? `$('#power').html(data.p)` replaces the contents of the select with the value of `data.p`. Did you mean to write `if (data.p == "off")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing all the options from the selector when you do `$("#power").html(data.p)`. This sets the contents of the `<select>` element to the value of `data.p`. It returns the `$("#power")` jQuery object, which is never `== "off"`, so the `if` fails and the rest of the code never runs.

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
$("#power").val(data.p == "off" ? "0" : "1");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/6bLey9zo/13/)

In the demo I had to use `$.post` instead of `$.getJSON`, because jsfiddle's AJAX server requires the POST method for JSON requests. But that shouldn't affect the way the response is processed.

The whole code should look like:

```
function updateStatus(){
  $.getJSON('/status.json', function(data){
    $("#power").val(data.p == "off" ? "0" : "1").selectmenu("refresh");
  }).fail(function(err){
    console.log("err getJSON mesures.json "+JSON.stringify(err));
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried `$("#power").val(data.p == "off" ? "0" : "1");` But that didnt work. I have also tried `if ($("#power").val(data.p == "off") {
  $("#power").val($("#power option:eq(0)").val());
  $("#power").selectmenu("refresh");
  } ` but same result

Comment: It seems like you're just putting things together without actually understanding what they do. Why would you put `data.p == "off"` in the argument to `.val()`? That will set the value to either `true` or `false`, not `0` or `1`. And why do you have it inside `if()` when it's not returning a truth value?

Comment: Thank you. I am not an expert and that's why I am asking in this fora.I see that your example works but mine doesn't. As you see I am using jQuery mobile 1.4.5 and if I add that script source and stylesheet in your fiddle it doesn't work anymore

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what I think your whole function should look like, including the `.selectmenu()` call.